# How to draw a filled polygon

Tags: flutter, canvas

How to draw a filled polygon in flutter?

Currently I am able to a eyebrow shape with array of point like below.

```
Path leftEyePath = Path();
leftEyePath.moveTo(leftEye[0].getX(),leftEye[0].getY());//starting point
for(int i=1;i<leftEye.length;i++){
  leftEyePath.lineTo(leftEye[i].getX(),leftEye[i].getY());
}
canvas.drawPath(leftEyePath,painter);
```

The code above will eventually draw a connected polygon with many line , but how do I draw a filled polygon with color I want?

EDIT:
I am currently go through their function and found drawShadow(..)

```
canvas.drawShadow(leftEyePath, Colors.orange[600],0,true);
```

Unfortunately it only draw **transparent color**.

Below is my current output.

[image]

Comment: see `Paint.style`

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu tried , nothing change. Am I missing something?

Comment: tried `Paint.style`?

Comment: @pskink you got it right , tried style = PaintingStyle.fill , it worked perfectly!

Comment: btw, have You tried `path.addPolygon(leftEye, true);` instead of moveTo/lineTo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may change your paint style into **PaintingStyle.fill**. The paint brush will automatically fill up the closing area of your path.

```
  Paint _filledPainter = new Paint()
    ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
  ;
```